# Write Ant task with a list of files as argument

Tags: java, ant, task

I would like to write an Ant task in Java which gets a list of files as argument (the list may be of varying size).

I know that you can extend the `Task` class and write setters to set
parameters, but I do not know how to handle a whole list of values.

Comment: [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-tasks-filesets-properties.html) there are some custom tasks which may help you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a new Ant Task, you may use a [macrodef](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) with element. 
Some example with an element that takes 1-n filesets, to include files from different locations :

```
<project>

 <macrodef name="listdirs">
  <attribute name="file"/>
  <element name="fs"/>
  <sequential>
   <pathconvert property="listcontents" pathsep="${line.separator}">
    <fs/>
   </pathconvert>
     <echo message="${listcontents}" file="@{file}" append="true"/>
   </sequential>
 </macrodef>

 <listdirs file="listdirs.txt">
  <fs>
   <fileset dir="c:\WKS\_nexus_"/>
   <!-- your other filesets .. -->
  </fs>
 </listdirs>

</project>
```

The tasks inside `sequential` are excuted for every nested fileset inside `fs` element.

Comment: I am not so fluent in Ant, so excuse my question: I need to give a set of files from Ant to a Java method. How does that fit into your approach?

Comment: @JFMeier Please provide more details : what do you want to do with your files ? The nested filesets can be processed with other ant tasks, including script task; my example uses pathconvert and echo on all files of nested filesets

Comment: Ok, I see. The fileset can also contain an explicit list of files. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use MatchingTask with a DirectoryScanner: http://javadoc.haefelinger.it/org.apache.ant/1.8.1/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/MatchingTask.html

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MatchingTask;

/**
 *
 * @author  anthony
 */
public class GetSizeTask extends MatchingTask {

    private String property;
    private String[] files;
    protected Vector filesets = new Vector();

    /** Creates a new instance of GetSizeTask */
    public GetSizeTask() {
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

   /**
    * Adds a set of files to be deleted.
    * @param set the set of files to be deleted
    */
    public void addFileset(FileSet set) {
        filesets.addElement(set);
    }

    public void execute() {
        if (property == null) {
            throw new BuildException("A property must be specified.");
        }
        if (getProject()==null) {
            project = new Project();
            project.init();
        }
        long totalSize = 0l;
        for (int i = 0; i < filesets.size(); i++) {
            FileSet fs = (FileSet) filesets.elementAt(i);
            DirectoryScanner ds = fs.getDirectoryScanner(getProject());
            files = ds.getIncludedFiles();
            for (int j=0; j<files.length; j++) {
                File file = new File(ds.getBasedir(), files[j]);
                totalSize += file.length();
            }
        }
        getProject().setNewProperty(property, NumberFormat.getInstance().format(totalSize));
    }

    public String[] getFoundFiles() {
        return files;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my files are not in one directory, they are at different places. I would like to be able to get an explicit list of files from Ant.